# How can I programmatically connect various points as a "blob" in an SVG?

Tags: python, math, svg, equation, graphing

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to create borders around a set of points similar to [borders in Stellaris](https://stellaris.gamejunkie.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Thinner-Borders-Mod-for-Stellaris.jpg), such that they're smoothly connected to each other, creating separate enclaves if necessary. I need this in an SVG format because I'm going to overlay these over an existing interactive SVG file that actually plots these points within a website I'm making. I'm trying to do this in python, but it's not a huge deal if I have to use a different language.

This is more of a conceptual question rather than a debugging question, so I don't really have any snippets to put here.

**How I've tried to do it:**

I've created the [equations](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k9gswzbsos) that match the shape I'm trying to make in desmos, but I'm having trouble translating that into actual code:

- My initial idea was to use a path or curve, since that can then be filled in with a color as well. Issue being, that would require the boundary of the inequality to be converted into a Beizer curve, which in my understanding can't be done programmatically.
- After that, I looked into metaballs following [this guide](https://varun.ca/metaballs/) and [another](https://medium.com/@tbarrasso/advanced-meta-metaballs-864bbf0a945c), since those roughly matched what I was going for, but they either didn't generalize to a variable amount of points, or couldn't deal with separating points.
- I also considered just iterating over an image with the equation and coloring it accordingly, but that would output to a PNG rather than an SVG, and it generally seems like a really inefficient way to go about this.

Am I missing something here? Is this even possible?

Edit: As per an idea given in the comments, I'm trying to use Marching Squares, nothing concrete just yet but it seems promising.

Edit: I ended up using a bit of a mix of Voronoi Diagrams and Square Marching, using Voronoi to determine the regions and then Square Marching to smoothen it and export the region into an SVG. I'll post code once I get some good results.

Comment: You question is really difficult to understand. Can you update the question with some code, maybe in a snippet. Pleas quaint yourself with this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wanted to post snippets, but the issue is that I'm having issues figuring out how to approach this problem. I tried to add as much detail as I can, though I can try to edit things to be more clear.

Comment: If you can point me to what specifically needs to be expanded on, I'll try to expand on it

Comment: A couple of suggestions: (1) Try placing a rectangular or triangular grid over your points and using an algorithm like [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to trace out contours based on the distances of each vertex to the neighbouring points. (2) Partition the 2D plane into a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and colour each cell according to the enclosed point.

Comment: I'm not sure if a Voronoi Diagram would work for my purposes, but I think the Marching Squares idea may work perfectly for this. I'll try that and update once I have something.